Application in Xamarin Forms and it stopped working on iPhones that updated to iOS 18.0
I have an application in Xamarin Forms and it stopped working on iPhones that updated to iOS 18.0
The first time I compile the application it works normally, but if I finish it and open it again, it crashes and becomes practically inoperative.
I develop in Visual Studio for Mac. As a solution I updated Xcode to 16 and Visual Studio, but without success.
Do I have any solution so I can make it work for iPhones that are on the iOS 18 version normally in Xamarin Forms or will I need to migrate to .NET MAUI?
As a solution I updated Xcode to 16 and Visual Studio, but without success.

without knowing why its crashing there is no way for us to suggest a fix

@Jason
the problem is that it doesn't give an error, it just hangs and doesn't return any error in the log. If I run it on an iPhone with iOS under 18, it works fine. What information could I provide that would help to reproduce?

be sure all the suspect code has appropriate exception handling, add some crash reporting tools like Raygun or Sentry

In my case the problem was because I used the MainPage as a TabbedPage from the Xamarin Community Toolkit, and apparently after the iOS 18.0 update, this can no longer occur. Now I'm setting my MainPage first as a ContentPage and then navigating to my TabbedPage.
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
{
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Login());
}

[...]

  MainPage = new NavigationPage(new TabMainPage());


NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false) seems to be a cause of this issue. So far the only solution I've found is to remove this or place in the OnAppearing() method rather than the constructor, unfortunately this causes some UI glitches, trying to find a workaround for this at the moment.
** edit **
Actually, the best solution seems to be to do it in OnSizeAllocated() as that has no knock-on effects on the UI:
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    if(NavigationPage.GetHasNavigationBar(this))
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
}

Also, XCode 16 seems to be incompatible with Xamarin.iOS (whatever IDE you're using). If you've already upgraded use the 'Xcodes' app to install XCode 15 alongside 16 and build using 15 instead. Note that, after installing the simulators with XCode 16, you can then run Xamarin apps on them after switching back to 15 using Xcodes.

In my case the problem was because I used the MainPage as a TabbedPage from the Xamarin Community Toolkit, and apparently after the iOS 18.0 update, this can no longer occur. Now I'm setting my MainPage first as a ContentPage and then navigating to my TabbedPage.

This might happen if you set the NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar = false in xaml file, or you called the NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false) in the Page Constructor, this is the main reason for the crash in iOS 18.0.
The simplest solution is that you have to call NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false) in the OnAppear() and the issue will be resolved. I had the same problem, and the above tricks work for me without any other issues.
